# What am I doing with this triple integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am new here and hope my question is clear and is straight to the point. The following is a form of an integral I am trying to compute.

$$\int_{x}\int_{y}\int_{z} f(x,y,z) g(x,y)\ dz \ dy \ dx \   $$

Assume that I tackle this problem (for some reason because its extremely hard to find in closed form) in the following way

1. First assign values of x and y, for example $$x=0:0.1:1000$$
   $$y=0:0.1:1000$$ and then compute the following

$$Y(i,j)= \int f(x(i),y(j),z) \ dz $$

where $i$ and $j$ are indices that run through the length of $x$ and $y$.

2. Next I take sample mean of $Y$. Let us call this average $$ \mu_y$$
3. I compute the following integral 
   $$\int_{x}\int_{y} \mu_y \ g(x,y) \ dy \ dx \   $$

which in my case is easy to compute !

As you see these steps are suboptimal, I simply want to have your expert opinion on this method.

a- When is my approximation good, i.e under what conditions ?

b- Do you have any other suggestions on how to approach optimality?

Thanks and hope it was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see a problem with some kinds of functions:

Let the domain of integration be $[0,1]^3$,

$$
f(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} \alpha &: 0 \leq x,y \leq \frac12, \\
                         0 &: \textrm{otherwise}; \end{cases}\\
g(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & : 0 \leq x,y, \leq \frac12,\\
                        1 &: \textrm{otherwise}; \end{cases}
$$
Then $\int\int\int fg\,dx\,dy\,dz=0$, but $\int\int\mu g\,dy\,dx = \frac{\alpha}{16}$ (so for large $\alpha$, the error is proportionally large). The problem is that you're levelling-out $f$, including its support, so if $g$ has disjoint support, that fact gets lost by your approximation. Similarly, if $f$ and $g$ are concentrated around the same points in $x,y$, then the actual integral could be much larger than the approximate one.

I would say, as long as you're discretizing and approximating, just go all the way and use the "trapezoid" rule (you should be able to find coded examples on the internet).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, the problem is that the triple integral that I am trying to evaluate has for $x,y,z$ the following limits $[0,+\infty]$, $[x,+\infty]$, $[y,+\infty]$ respectively. Not sure this can be done by Riemman or Trapezoid rule

Comment: Well, the functions must decay sufficiently at $\infty$ for these integrals to be defined, right? If you take a large enough, finite region as the domain of integration, it will be approximately equal to the actual integral.

Comment: They do decay. Do you mean take a large enough finite region over $x,y,z$ and evaluate numerically as in Riemann Sum or any other method? From your experience, do you happen to know what would be a good step size? for example say I take x:0.1:1000 and same for y and z.  I am not sure if this is outside the scope of this site. But I tried using MATLAB to approximate but Reimman sum it is taking DAYS to compute for that reason I did what I described in my question above.

Comment: Yep, take a large finite region, and use some kind of Riemann sum. How large depends on how fast the function decays; you might put some work into estimating that "tail" to see how large a region is needed to get close. I would think matlab would do reasonably well with this, but of course that depends on the size of the grid (how "large" as well as how closely spaced), how complicated the function is to evaluate, and how the code is written. You can try your program on small grids to get an idea how long larger grids will take, using `tic` and `toc` or better yet the profiler, then scaling.

Comment: Also using the built in matlab functions is probably faster than writing three nested loops, I think that, if `mat` is a 3D-matrix with the function values, then `trapz(x,trapz(y,trapz(z,mat,3),2),1);` (see link below) will give you what you want. Construct `mat` by way of something like `[x,y,z] = meshgrid(0:0.1:1000); mat = F(x,y,z);` (I might have got the syntax wrong, but my point here is to get matlab to build `mat` for you; **do not** write loops).

(see here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40672-3d-trapezoidal-rule/content//trapezoidal_rule_triple_integral.m

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understand what you mean, one more question though, you see if I use meshgrid to create my points, how can I include the limits that I have on my variables, that is notice that the limit for example on $y$ is from $\int_{x}^{\infty}$ while that on $z$ is $\int_{y}^{\infty}$ any ideas on how I can account for that while using meshgrid. If I use loops this is easy to do, by just adding an extra condition, while with meshgrid I am not sure how one can account for such limits?

Comment: Use logical statements in the definition of the function to be integrated. For instance $\int_0^1\int_y^1 f(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \int_0^1\int_0^1 \chi_{\{x > y\}}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$. Just define the function similarly `F(x,y) = (x > y).*f(x,y)`.

Comment: very nice trick ! thanks